# Asking to Mingw to copy some source during compilation

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw-w64

I have some ressouces (png/sound...)  in a folder named "datas" itself stored in a folder contening my code cpp. I want to know if it is possible to ask Mingw during compilation to copy the "datas" folder to the output folder?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on your build-system. If you use `make` and makefiles then yes it's possible. And if you use an IDE then could have things like pre-build or post-build steps that can run arbitrary commands or scripts.

Comment: Thank @Someprogrammerdude I will take a look at my IDE then.